# Register mock service URL

Tags: angular, http, http-mock

In the `hero.service.ts` file for Angular's quick start example, [step 7](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview), is this snippet of code:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

I tried to translate it into my app like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private dataUrl = 'api/data';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl) // <-- error here
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as MyData[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

I got a `404 - Collection`data`not found` on the `this.http.get` line, which is completely understandable since it's just a random path. There's no API at that endpoint.

**Question:** how did the Angular example work? Where did it register the `api/heroes` path for mock HTTP requests?

Comment: So, you follow a tutorial, but you don't read it? https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#simulate-the-web-api

Comment: @JBNizet I saw it and added the `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)` to my `app.module.ts`. Still not working

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: As in still giving the 404 error. I've had that line all this time

Comment: You get a 404 for which URL?

Comment: The URL is `api/data`

Comment: Why do you expect an in-memory web API designed for a tutorial about heroes, containing instructions to get heroes from the URL api/heroes, to provide anything on the URL api/data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Angular's regular HTTP module, the command:

```
return this.http.get(this.dataUrl)
```

expects `this.dataUrl` to be a string containing the address of a real HTTP web service. (Such as [`"http://swapi.co/api/people/1/"`](http://swapi.co/api/people/1/).)

In "regular use", that command will make a request to the HTTP service at `this.dataUrl`.

But... your code is taken from the tutorial, which changes things a bit.

If you would recall, the tutorial asked for you to add the `InMemoryWebApiModule` to your `@NgModule`:

```
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Those lines you add create a service that, roughly speaking, *hijacks* your http requests, preventing them from reaching the real server of the URL you give (say `myserver.com/api/heroes`), but instead making those requests go to a *fake server*.

<sub><sup>(For details, notice that `InMemoryWebApiModule` comes from `angular-in-memory-web-api`. So check https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api to understand how it works.)</sup></sub>

Now, that fake server has to return some data to be useful. Where does it come from?

This is where the "second part" of `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)`, namely `InMemoryDataService`, comes into play.

At the demo from [Angular docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#simulate-the-web-api) notice that `InMemoryDataService` is defined at `'./in-memory-data.service'`:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 0,  name: 'Zero' },
      ...
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }
}
```

Now, the important part here is the returning command `return {heroes};`. <sup>(If you are unfamiliar with the syntax, that is short for `return {heroes: heroes};`)</sup>.

The [**keys** of that returned object **define the available URLs**](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api#basic-usage) at the fake server.

Since you are returning `{heroes: <something>}`, the URL `api/heroes` will be available at the fake server. If you returned `{foo: <something>}`, then the URL `api/foo` would be available.

As you want `api/data` to be available, then return something like `{data: ...}` would do:

```
createDb() {
  const data = [
    { id: 0, name: 'AAAA' },
    { id: 1, name: 'BBBB' },
    ...
  ];
  return {data};
}
```

So that's it, that's what you need to change.

Now, keep in mind that, for production (*real*) code, you should remove that whole `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)` thing and have a real web service responding at `this.dataUrl`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find that the API was connected to the returned data's key in the tutorial